# How do I use php-fpm on RHEL 7.2?

Tags: php, apache, rhel7

I'm new to configuring Apache and I'm trying to optimize my Apache server. Reading through the documentation, I found that I should be using the **Event MPM** instead of the **Prefork MPM**. Everything was straight forward until this point as I only had to comment out Prefork and uncomment Event in **00-mpm.conf**. However, when I restarted Apache, I got the following error -

```
AH00526: Syntax error on line 31 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf: Invalid command 'php_value', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

Digging for some more information, I found out that mod_php should not be used with Event. So, I'm commented out **php_value** in **php.conf** and also commented out **LoadModule** in **10-php.conf**.

My webpages wouldn't load anymore and I realized that I should be using **php-fpm**. However, documentation regarding this is really unclear and I'm not sure how to use it. I tried this -

```
    [root@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx ~]# yum install php-fpm
Loaded plugins: amazon-id, rhui-lb, search-disabled-repos
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php70w-fpm.x86_64 0:7.0.4-1.w7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php70w-common(x86-64) = 7.0.4-1.w7 for package: php70w-fpm-7.0.4-1.w7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php70w-common.x86_64 0:7.0.4-1.w7 will be installed
--> Processing Conflict: php70w-common-7.0.4-1.w7.x86_64 conflicts php-common < 5.5.0
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: php70w-common conflicts with php-common-5.4.16-36.el7_1.x86_64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I'm not sure how to proceed and would really appreciate any help with this problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to remove your current installation of php and php-common will be uninstalled as a dependency.

I can confirm that I have just done this and found that when I uninstalled php a large number of related packages were also removed, so you will need to add the relevant php70w versions of various plugins (such as php70w-fpm, php70w-mysql, etc)

I also found that roundcube was uninstalled, but am now planning to install the latest version of this now that I have PHP 7